# Equation for relative Kinetic energy

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, inertial-frames, mass-energy

Relative Kinetic energy is given by

K.E = ($\gamma$-1)$m_0$c²; where $m_0$ is rest mass

but can it also be given by this

K.E= $\frac{1}{2}\gamma m_0v²$;
where v is velocity of particle

can it?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112343/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/414787/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332549/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/718482/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47378/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/115077/226902 (and MANY more...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In special relativity, the total energy of an object is given by; $$E = \sqrt{ (pc)^2 + (m_0 c^2)^2} = \sqrt{(\gamma m_0 v c)^2 +(m_0 c^2)^2}$$ where $p$ is the relativistic momentum $(\gamma m v)$.

The kinetic energy is the total energy minus the rest energy, so:

$$E_K = E - m_0 c^2 =  \sqrt{(\gamma m_0 v c)^2 +(m_0 c^2)^2} - m_0 c^2$$

If you rearrange this equation you get : $$ E_K^2 + 2 E_K m_0 c^2 - (\gamma m_0 v c)^2 =0 \ .$$ This is a quadratic equation and the positive root is $$E_k = m_0 c^2 (\gamma -1)  $$ in agreement with your first equation and [as documented by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy).

If you take the Taylor expansion of this expression, the first three terms are: $$0 + \frac 1 2 m_0 v^2 + \frac 3 8 \frac{m_0 v^4} {c^2} $$

When v is small compared to c the terms with powers of v greater than 2 become negligible and the equation approximates to the Newtonian expectation $ 1/2 m v^2$. The Newtonian equation is not strictly correct and is superseded by the relativistic equation, but for velocities encountered in everyday mechanics the Newtonian equation is a reasonable and convenient approximation.

Your second equation $\gamma (1/2 \ m_0 v^2)$ is not equal to either the relativistic or the Newtonian equation for kinetic energy. For example, if we assume $$1/2 \gamma m v^2  = m_0 c^2 (\gamma -1)  $$ this equivalence eventually reduces to $$\frac{v^2}{c^2} = 0$$ which can only be true if v=0.

> How come it reduces to $v^2/c^2=0$ ?

$$1/2 \gamma \ m v^2  = m_0 c^2 (\gamma -1)  $$

$$ \gamma \ v^2/c^2  = 2 (\gamma -1)  $$

Substitute x for v^2/c^2

$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x} }  =  \frac{2 (1 - \sqrt{1-x})}{\sqrt{1-x}}  $$

$$ {x}  = 2 (1 - \sqrt{1-x})  $$

$$ 2 \sqrt{1-x}  = 2-x $$

$$ 4 (1-x)  = (2-x)^2 $$

$$  -x^2 = 0$$

$$  x = 0$$

Comment: How come [it reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%28%5Cgamma-1%29+m+c%5E2+%3D+1%2F2+%5Cgamma+m+v%5E2+for+%5Cgamma) to $v^2/c^2 = 0$ ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Added how I obtained that result to the end of my question. Your result is not wrong. Mine is different because I opened up the gamma factor to expose the $v^2 /c^2$ and then solved for that. We don't disagree.

Comment: Oh, I begin to understand. I get the same conclusion of $v=0$ if I equate $\gamma_{fake} = \gamma$.

Comment: The easy way is plot the two graphs and see where they cross ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Relativistic kinetic energy is difference of relativistic energy and rest energy of object.
To check that your proposal does not hold,- simply try to equate these expressions, like :

$$ \tag 1 (\gamma-1)m_0c^2 = \frac 12 \gamma m_0v^2 $$

Then after a couple of equation simplification steps (leaving this for you as an exercise), you will get that your gamma factor has form :

$$\tag 2 \gamma_{fake} = \frac {1}{1- {v^2}/({2c^2})}$$

This fake factor differs from true Lorentz factor $\gamma ={\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-{\frac {v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}}}$ mainly by 2 aspects :

- Square root in denominator is lost
- in your case, maximum possible body speed is $\sqrt 2 ~c$ which is greater than speed limit $c$.

Hence you can't assume new form of relativistic kinetic energy expression. It's already [well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy).